# Выполнить код на странице определенной записи Word Press

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте. В cms Word Press создал рубрику, в этой рубрике создал запись, запись имеет **id 46** (post=46).

Я хочу вывести свой код только на этой записи, для этого мне нужно условие, которое проверяет на какой записи я нахожусь. 
Буду благодарен за информацию!

Для того чтобы было понятнее про что я: если бы я хотел выполнить свой код на определенной странице, я бы использовал условие:

```
<? if ((is_page('15'))) { ?>
первый код
<? }else{ ?>
мой код 2
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получение ID поста в wordpress происходит следующим образом:

```
$id = get_the_ID();
```

Следовательно, ваше условие должно быть таким:

```
<? if (get_the_ID() == 46) { ?>
```

Документация: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/

Comment: спасибо вам большое. через 5мин приму ответ